# Did the Semiconductor Industry Association criticize exports restriction to China before?

Tags: united-states, china, trade, lobbying

https://www.bbc.com/news/business-67141987

> Nvidia has said in a filing that the new export restrictions will block sales of two high-end artificial intelligence chips it created for the Chinese market - A800 and H800. It said that one of its gaming chips will also be blocked.
>
> Although the curbs also affect other chip makers, analysts believe Nvidia will be hit the hardest because China accounts for up to 25% of its revenues from data centre chip sales. Nvidia's shares, which are considered a star stock, fell by as much as 4.7% in the wake of the announcement.
>
> The Semiconductor Industry Association, which represents 99% of the US semiconductor industry by revenue, said in a statement that the new measures are "overly broad" and "risk harming the US semiconductor ecosystem without advancing national security as they encourage overseas customers to look elsewhere".

Did the Semiconductor Industry Association publicly state such criticism of any prior actions the US government took regarding exports to China? (Wikipedia [documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_Industry_Association#Tariffs_on_China) that SIA was critical of the Trump administration limiting *imports* from China. I'm asking about exports here.)

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:**
> Did the Semiconductor Industry Association criticize exports restriction to China before?

Barely a peep.

> **[SIA Statement on New Export Controls](https://www.semiconductors.org/sia-statement-on-new-export-controls-2/)**
>
> Tuesday, Oct 17, 2023, 9:00am
>
> “We are evaluating the impact of the updated export controls on the U.S. semiconductor industry. We recognize the need to protect national security and believe maintaining a healthy U.S. semiconductor industry is an essential component to achieving that goal. Overly broad, unilateral controls risk harming the U.S. semiconductor ecosystem without advancing national security as they encourage overseas customers to look elsewhere. Accordingly, we urge the administration to strengthen coordination with allies to ensure a level playing field for all companies.”

Biden last year invested $52.7 billion in the semiconductor industry (foreign and domestic).  This goes into research and development but also in subsidies for manufacturing and education.  Huge grants.

Yes China likely accounts for a third of their business.  But I think they are still happy to get the US taxpayer money and warry of losing it for poking the gift horse in the shins.

- 2022, **[Chips and Sciences Act](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/statements-releases/2022/08/09/fact-sheet-chips-and-science-act-will-lower-costs-create-jobs-strengthen-supply-chains-and-counter-china/)**